Postgres SSL connection error in Docker/Portainer despite SSL explicitly disabled
I'm trying to deploy a FastAPI application with PostgreSQL using Docker Compose in Portainer, but I'm getting SSL-related connection errors despite explicitly disabling SSL. It works on local, but when deploying to Portainer, the next error araises:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "db" (172.27.0.2), port 5432 failed: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required

docker-compose.yml
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./balancer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - stack.env
    environment:
      PORT: 8000
      PYTHONPATH: /app
      ENVIRONMENT: production
      DISABLE_SSL: "true"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - stack.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    command: 
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "ssl=off"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

database.py
def get_database_url():
    if settings.USE_SQLITE:
        return settings.DATABASE_URL
    return f"postgresql://{settings.DATABASE_USER}:{settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD}@{settings.DATABASE_HOST}:{settings.DATABASE_PORT}/{settings.DATABASE}?sslmode=disable"

try:
    connect_args = {"check_same_thread": False} if settings.USE_SQLITE else {
        "connect_timeout": 5
    }
    engine = create_engine(
        get_database_url(),
        connect_args=connect_args,
        pool_pre_ping=True
    )

And these are the variables that appear in the Portainer info for the backend container:
0 DATABASE_HOST=db
1 DATABASE_PASSWORD=balancer
5 DATABASE_USER=balancer
12 DATABASE_PORT=5432
22 DATABASE=balancer
13 DISABLE_SSL=true

I've tried almost everything but I do not know how to continue with this. I don't get why it works locally but not on the Portainer.
Thanks in advance.

If you disable SSL on the database server, you shouldn't be surprised if you get connection errors with a client that tries an encrypted connection...

So what does the database URL end up being after all that mumbo jumbo is done to it?
